# Pause key in Linux Mint is acting on both RhythmBox and Youtube videos

Tags: keyboard, linux-mint, youtube, rhythmbox

I'm using Linux Mint 20.  My Multimedia pause/play button on my keyboard as expected can be used to pause and resume playback in Rhythmbox. However, if I have a youtube video paused in some tab or embedded in some page that isn't even in focus, if I press pause/play, it will resume that video as well. I'm wondering if there is a way to limit the button to only act on Rhythmbox or if it's always a global thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this is a recent question, you're on Linux Mint, and the recent Firefox version added this feature, I'm assuming that your browser is a recent version of Firefox. If I'm wrong, disregard this.

You're experiencing [a known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1615665). Rather than making your media control only work on Rhythmbox, the quick solution is to make it not work on Firefox. Open about:config and search for the setting `media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled` - disabling this and restarting your browser should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed it. I had searched the about:config in Firefox for "pause" but didn't think to search for hardware or mediakeys. Hmmm. Also, the same thing happened when I tried it in Chrome so I thought maybe it was a Mint thing.